# Why is my app in iOS going to a different screen when calling another one?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift2

My issue is here, I have an app that is adding another screen to the stack when going to one different. I'm calling the right segue but it goes Menu->Screen 1-> Real Destination.

Here: [image]

From Menu is supposed to go to Camion, what it actually happens is that it goes first to the TabBarController is shows and then to the Camion and I' calling the right segue.

Code:

```
 else if segue.identifier == tabBarAvisosSegue {

        let tabBarAvisosVC = segue.destinationViewController as! TabBarAvisosViewController


        tabBarAvisosVC.selectedItem = item

        print("Avisos number sent \(item)")

        let tabBarAvisosFirst = tabBarAvisosVC.viewControllers![0] as! TabBarAvisosTableViewController

        if avisosDictionaryAlumno.count > 0 {

            tabBarAvisosFirst.avisosAlumno = avisosDictionaryAlumno
        } else {

            tabBarAvisosFirst.avisosAlumno = []

        }

        let tabBarPrivadosSecond = tabBarAvisosVC.viewControllers![1] as! TabBarPrivadosTableViewController

        if privadosDictionaryAlumno.count > 0 {

            tabBarPrivadosSecond.privadosAlumno = privadosDictionaryAlumno

        } else {

            tabBarPrivadosSecond.privadosAlumno = []


        }

        tabBarAvisosVC.selectedIndex = 0



    } else if segue.identifier == satsCamionSegue {

        let satsCamionVC = segue.destinationViewController as! SatsCamionViewController

    }
```

I'm doing the prepare for segue to  set the tabbar to the right controller when I call that, but I'm not doing that segue.

Here:

```
@IBAction func camionTapped(sender: UIButton) {

    item = 2

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier(satsCamionSegue, sender: self)
}
```

Any help?

EDIT 1:

So to clarify this is what is happening I have the Menu and three buttons as shown, when I tap the Camion escolar button it should show the MapView down only so the back button returns to the Menu. What is actually doing is pushing the TabBar controller first displaying another screen for a second and then the actual screen called for the segue. So it does this Menu->Screen 1->Camion escolar. And when I tap the back button what it does goes back yes but the Screen 1 not to the Menu.

Comment: I am not understating your problem, can you explain it differently?

Comment: Yes, I will try see edit

Comment: Fixed check always your copies of the buttons they maybe carry extra baggage :)